# Retrieving data from SQL database and Display in Treeview form

Tags: wpf, api

I have three tables in SQL database which I would like to display in treeview in my App, tbFlights, tbRegions, Tbcountries. The FLight should be a child and the fall under different regions and countries..............................................................................

```
    using Admin_Tool.Classes;
    using Common.Classes;
    using Common.Enums;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    namespace Admin_Tool.ViewModels
    {
        public class ViewFlightsViewModel : ViewModelBaseExtended
        {
            #region Properties

            private Collection<SefFlight> _flightList = null;
            public Collection<SefFlight> FlightList
            {
                get
                {
                    return _flightList = _flightList ?? new Collection<SefFlight>();
                }
            }

            private Collection<Region> _regionList = null;
            public Collection<Region> RegionList
            {
                get
                {
                    return _regionList = _regionList ?? new Collection<Region>();
                }
            }

            #region Flight View

            private bool _showLayout1 = true;
            public bool ShowLayout1
            {
                get
                {
                    return _showLayout1;
                }
                set
                {
                    _showLayout1 = value;
                }
            }

            //private static List<SefFlight> _sefFlightGroup = null;
            //public static List<SefFlight> SefFlightGroup
            //{
            //    get
            //    {
            //        return _sefFlightGroup = _sefFlightGroup ?? new List<SefFlight>();
            //    }
            //}

            //private static Dictionary<int, TreeViewItemViewModel> _itemGroupsList = null;
            //public static Dictionary<int, TreeViewItemViewModel> ItemGroupsList
            //{
            //    get
            //    {
            //        return _itemGroupsList = _itemGroupsList ?? new Dictionary<int, TreeViewItemViewModel>();
            //    }
            //}
            #endregion

            #region 

            #endregion

            #endregion

            #region Constructors

            public ViewFlightsViewModel(MainViewModel parent) : base (parent)
            {
                LoadSefFlight();
                LoadRegions();
            }
            #endregion

            #region Methods

            private void LoadSefFlight()
            {
                try
                {
                    FlightList.Clear();

                    var result = Common.Helpers.WebRequests.Invoke(ApiInventoryUrls.List_SefFlights, null, null);

                    if (result.IsSuccessful)
                    {
                        foreach (var flight in (List<SefFlight>)result.Result)
                            FlightList.Add(flight);
                        LoadRegions();
                    }
                    else
                        ShowError(result.ErrorMessage);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ShowError(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            private void LoadRegions()
            {
                try
                {
                    RegionList.Clear();

                    var result = Common.Helpers.WebRequests.Invoke(ApiInventoryUrls.List_RegionLists, null, null);

                    if (result.IsSuccessful)
                    {
                        foreach (var region in (List<Region>) result.Result)
                            RegionList.Add(region);
                    }
                    else
                        ShowError(result.ErrorMessage);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
            }
            #endregion


            #region Overrides

            public override void Refresh()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            #endregion

            #region Relay Commands

            #endregion

            #region Commands

            #endregion
        }
    }
```

The below is my view where I am displaying my data.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Admin_Tool.Views.ViewFlightsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Admin_Tool.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Ribbon Visibility="{Binding ShowRibbon}">
            <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
                <RibbonApplicationMenu Visibility="Collapsed" />
            </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <RibbonTab Header="Home">
                <RibbonGroup Header="Actions">
                    <RibbonButton LargeImageSource="/Common;component/Resources/home.png"
                                Label="Home"
                                Command="{Binding CloseCommand}">
                    </RibbonButton>
                </RibbonGroup>
                <RibbonGroup Header="Tools">
                    <RibbonButton LargeImageSource="/Common;component/Resources/Edit.png"
                                Label="Edit"
                                Command="{Binding CloseCommand}">
                    </RibbonButton>
                </RibbonGroup>
            </RibbonTab>
        </Ribbon>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <TextBlock Text="Flights" 
                       FontSize="25" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Block.LineHeight="45" />
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" 
                       Text="Scheduled Flights"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <GroupBox>
                    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding FlightList}">
                        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <!-- 
    This Style binds a TreeViewItem to a PersonViewModel. 
    -->
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

                        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding FlightList}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    </TreeView>
                </GroupBox>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="Scheduled Legs" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" 
                  Grid.Column="1">
                <GroupBox>
                    <TreeView Name="trvList2">
                        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredPrincipalList}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                    </TreeView>
                </GroupBox>
            </Grid>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" 
                       Text=" View Scheduled Flights"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       />
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" 
                  Grid.Column="2">
                <GroupBox></GroupBox>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>






</UserControl>
```

Comment: FlightList must be an Observablecollection, and implement INotifyPropertyChanged and make sure after your list is complete change notification occurs

Comment: It was not me that downvote, but I know why you received it, you need to better explain your problem, tell what is happening, by your description we must guess that your data does not appear, your code is ok, we can see what it is to be done, there are parts that could be omitted, but overall this is ok

Answer (score 0):

`FlightList` must be an `Observablecollection`, and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and make sure after your list is complete change notification occurs.

I will consider that the `INotifyPropertyChanged` is in the `ViewModelBaseExtended` class, and I will not approach it here, just use it

here are the changes, so it should solve your problem

```
private ObservableCollection<SefFlight> _flightList = null;
public ObservableCollection<SefFlight> FlightList
{
    get
    {
        return _flightList ?? new ObservableCollection<SefFlight>();
    }
    set 
    {
        _flightList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FlightList));  // implement INotifyPropertyChanged
    }

}

private ObservableCollection<Region> _regionList = null;
public ObservableCollection<Region> RegionList
{
    get
    {
        return _regionList ?? new ObservableCollection<Region>();
    }
    set 
    {
        _regionList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RegionList));  // implement INotifyPropertyChanged
    }
}

private void LoadSefFlight()
{
    try
    {
        var flightList = new List<SefFlight>();  //         <-- there was change here
        var result = Common.Helpers.WebRequests.Invoke(ApiInventoryUrls.List_SefFlights, null, null);

        if (result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            foreach (var flight in (List<SefFlight>)result.Result)
                flightList.Add(flight); //                  <-- there was change here

            FlightList = new ObservableCollection<SefFlight>(flightList); //    <-- there was change here
            LoadRegions();
        }
        else
            ShowError(result.ErrorMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ShowError(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void LoadRegions()
{
    try
    {
        var regionList = new List<Region>();  //            <-- there was change here

        var result = Common.Helpers.WebRequests.Invoke(ApiInventoryUrls.List_RegionLists, null, null);

        if (result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            foreach (var region in (List<Region>) result.Result)
                regionList.Add(region); //                  <-- there was change here

            RegionList = new ObservableCollection<Region>(regionList); //<-- there was change here
        }
        else
            ShowError(result.ErrorMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```